# javascript insertBefore method results to "NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist."

Tags: javascript

here is my html:

```
<html><body>
page starts here
this is a test page
top:
<script id="invoc_code" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var xhr;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
           xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            var body = document.body;                                       
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                if(body.firstChild){
                    body.insertBefore(xhr.response, body.firstChild);
                } else {
                    body.appendChild(xhr.response);
                }
            }
       };
       xhr.open("GET", "http://google.com", true);
       xhr.send(); 
    };
</script>;

page ends here
</body></html>
```

line `body.insertBefore(xhr.response, body.firstChild);` results to "NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist". Can you please tell me what is the reason?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can only insert DOMNodes into the DOM. I doubt `xhr.response` is one.

Comment: I guess, there is no any child node of body

Comment: Right Marcell Fulop, thanks:)

Comment: anand4tech , there is text node as child node of body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore) method expects a DOM element as its first parameter. If the XHR response is a HTML string, then you need to create one using this. Depending on your required DOM output you could do something like this:

```
var newElem = document.createElement("div");
newElem.innerHTML = xhr.response;
body.insertBefore(newElem, body.firstChild);
```